# How to get correct type when duplicate class names in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In my main node js app I am getting a correct type for the Request object see below:

```
app.post("/upload", function (request: Request, response: Response, next: any) {
    var form: object = request.body;
    var name: string = form.name;
```

But when I break that code out into a separate class I believe I am losing the type.

```
app.post("/upload", function (request: Request, response: Response, next: any) {
   var responder = new Responder();
   responder.process(request, response, next);
```

Responder:
import express from "express";
import { Request } from "express";

```
export {};

export class Responder {
   async process(request: Request, response: Response, next: any) {
         var form: object = request.body;
         var name: string = form.name.toLowerCase(); // error on this line
```

Responder class:
[image]

Error:
[image]

I believe it is because there is a nodejs Request and an ExpressJS Request. I believe the compiler is getting confused.

I have tried importing the Request from express as shown in my code but it doesn't appear to be working.

If it is a type collision how do I avoid it?

Two types with the same name:

Request - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest
Request -  https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body

Although, now that I've looked it up it says that nodejs request is `httpclientrequest`. So why the compiler error?

Comment: Alias the type import from express: `import { Request as ExpressRequest } from 'express';`

Comment: @JaredSmith that seems to work. that could be an answer. what should I declare the`form` variable type as? That should be an answer

Comment: I would omit the annotation and let the compiler infer it, but I [sure wouldn't use object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGIBGArApsWBeGAbxgEMUBGGAXwCgEQA6NGAgJgG4YB6L1EABwgBCGqEggANlgYSQAcwAU9BiQCUnHjDQBLOXKwAnPoJpA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can aliasing the `Request` from one of the import.
For example you can:

```
import { Request as ExpressRequest } from 'express'
```

and then substituing all `Request` occurences with `ExpressRequest`.
In this way you disambiguate the type.

However you should not declare the type in the line like so:

```
var form: object = request.body;
```

But use:

```
var form = request.body;
```

In this way the compiler can infer the type.

In any case with language of High Level as Typescript or Python etc. etc. is suggested to not specify the type, in this way the compiler or the interpreter(in the case of Python) can infer the best type that fit the variable value.